# TinyMCE valid elements: only allow specific CSS rules

Tags: css, validation, tinymce

TinyMCE's `valid_elements` property lets you define a whitelist of valid HTML elements and their attributes. You can allow only paragraphs and links with this:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    valid_elements: 'p,a[href]'
});
```

However, the `style` attribute is a bit of a problem. It's needed for certain things like aligning, but if you allow it then it could contain all sorts of undesirable CSS rules. Is there any way to restrict its contents to only allow certain rules, something like this:

```
a[href|style=text-align,font-size,color]
```

Comment: You are using which version of tinymce?

Comment: Version 3.3.9.3, the latest stable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There you go, there is an undocumented option called "valid_styles".

More & Syntax: http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=21554

Comment: Yay for undocumented features!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, this is not possible with Version 3.3.9.3 .
It might be available in Version 3.4 because the validation implementation will be changed (anounced by Mociecode).