# How do I filter valid styles in a TinyMCE 4.x editor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

In TinyMCE version 3.3.9.4, it was possible to limit the styles to alignment (rejecting coloring options and the like), by using the ´undocumented´ `valid_styles` option ([TinyMCE valid elements: only allow specific CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165586/tinymce-valid-elements-only-allow-specific-css-rules/6498150#6498150)):

```
    valid_styles : { '*' : 'text-align' },
```

Now with the 4.x version, this doesn't seem to work any more. 
Is there a way to filter valid styles in TinyMCE 4.x, preferably by using built-in editor (client side) methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`valid_styles` seems **[well documented](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:valid_styles)** for version 4 :

> This option enables you specify the available styles for each element.
>   This means you can force ordering and only specific styles to be valid
>   within style attribute values. Specify the element name, then it's
>   styles or * for all elements.

```
tinymce.init({
    ...
    valid_styles: {
        "*": "border,font-size",
        "div": "width,height"
    }
});
```

Here is a [tinymce fiddle you can play with](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Sweaab).

Comment: For folks looking to use this currently, I can't get it to work with p and span elements, and have filed a support ticket with TinyMCE - https://support.ephox.com/hc/en-us/requests/8483

Comment: @Sébastien Can we specify the value of the styles attribute.
For example if I want to allow only bold value of font-weight not others